# Disconnect between adding a class and CSS getting applied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some annoying issues between Bootstrap/JQuery/my own CSS, tell me if this sounds like a problem you know how to fix.

I'm implementing my own "slider", with AJAX calls loading content onto the page depending on the navigation the user does. The problem comes in with my navbar. When an `onhashchange` event happens, I'm loading the correct content in, clearing the `active` class from the `<li>` element, and re-adding the `active` class to the appropriate `<li>` element.

Unfortunately, setting the `active` class isn't causing the appropriate CSS I have written to be applied, a slight darkening. There could be a million things causing THAT, I realize. But hardcoding an active class gives exactly the desired result. I don't know where the disconnect is. I ask myself, is a page loading problem getting in the way of the CSS being applied? I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

**HTML**:

```
...
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="sections nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#call">Call</a></li>
    <li><a href="#police">Police</a></li>
    <li><a href="#charges">Charges</a></li>
    <li><a href="#jail">Jail</a></li>
    <li><a href="#courts">Courts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#resources">Resources</a></li>
  </ul>
  ...
</div>
...
```

**My CSS**:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #231f20;
}

.navbar .sections>li>a:hover {
    background-color: #4f4c4d;
}

    /* Overriding */
.navbar a { color: #DDD !important; }
.navbar a:hover { color: #AAA !important; }
.navbar-nav>.active>a { background-color: #4f4c4d !important; }
```

**My JS**:

```
   /* Constants */

var elem = $('.sections li a');
var pages = [];
for(i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
  //console.log(elem[i])
  pages[i] = elem[i].hash;
}

var first = 0;
var last = pages.length;

...

function loadPage(hash, callback) {
/* Loads the content inside the "#main" element on the
   page found at <url> into the "#main" element of the 
   current page. Then sets the links and buttons 
   accordingly. */

  url = hash.split('#')[1] + '.html'
  $('#main').load(url + "#main", callback);
  setLinks(hash);
}


function setLinks(hash) {


  for (i=0; i<=last; i++) {
    if (pages[i] == hash) {
      page_num = i;
    }
  }

  var previous = page_num - 1;
  var next = page_num + 1;

  ...

  $('.sections li').removeClass('active');
  $('.sections li').eq(page_num).addClass('active');

}


$(document).ready(function() { 
  ...

  $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    loadPage(window.location.hash);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you shure you included the css files in the right order?(your customization last)

Comment: Yes, post code. Specifically, post the [**minimal** necessary code to replicate the issue](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Yep, been including my customization last since the beginning. The strange thing is, viewing the different CSS applied to an element in my browser ought to show me two conflicting bits of CSS applied if there was overlap. But it doesn't. There is only one piece of CSS applied to the `background-color` element.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the callback functionality offered in the function loadpage. You are doing an asynchronic call, and directly applying the css. However, the page has not been updated yet (it takes some time). You should do something like this (only the updated functions):

```
function loadPage(hash, callback) {
    /* Loads the content inside the "#main" element on the
       page found at <url> into the "#main" element of the 
       current page. Then sets the links and buttons 
       accordingly. */

    url = hash.split('#')[1] + '.html'
    $('#main').load(url + "#main", callback);
    // setLinks(hash); <-- don't do this, it will be executed to early!
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
...

  $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    loadPage(window.location.hash, setLinks); // <-- making use of the callback functionality
  });
});
```

And remove the `setLinks` call from the loadPage function itself. By passing it in as the callback function, it will get executed once the `$('#main').load` is finished.

Comment: I'm thinking that it has more to do with Bootstrap/CSS now that I'm looking at the problem with great scrutiny. Nevertheless, I took your advice.

Comment: Ok, I thought that might be the problem. I never had any rendering issues when I assign a classname appropriatly. Do you see the classname attached, but the styling not?

Comment: It could also be a conflicting style of course. When you hard-code the style in your browser devbar, it becomes an `inline` style property (like `<a href=#" style="styling here...">test</a>`), and then it weights more than any other styles, with the exeption of `!important` rules.